# Таймер срабатывает раньше чем надо

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему таймер не срабатывает строго каждые 30 секунд, а срабатывает значительно раньше, по ощущениям то через 15 сек, то через 20. Как-то не впопад работает..
Заметил, когда закрываешь приложение, таймер продолжает работать, и когда открываешь, работают уже два таймера.. Как тут подправить, или как обычно делается?

```
   public class ProcessingUnit extends TimerTask {
    public ProcessingUnit() {
        // конструктор
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // тут код, который надо вызывать по расписанию
         new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(mapsActivity, "999", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Запуск при старте программы

```
    ProcessingUnit processingUnit = new ProcessingUnit();
    long interval = 30L * 1000L; // 1 минута = 60 000 миллисекунд 
    Timer processingUnitTimer = new Timer();
    processingUnitTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(processingUnit, 0, interval);
```

Comment: `Toast` не показатель - он выводится в UI-потоке через его очередь, естественно задержка может быть любой и интервалы между показами соответственно. `Handler` создавать в каждом срабатывании не правильно - вынесите его в поле класса. С `Runnable` тоже самое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я пользуюсь следующим шаблоном таймера

```
//Включение таймера
if (timer!=null) timer.cancel();
timer = new Timer();
MyTimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
//Для одиночного повторения:
timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000);
//Для периодического повторения:
timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 5000);

//Выключение таймера
if (timer!=null) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}

//Определение задачи таймера
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Действия, составляющие задачу таймера
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть таймер надо всегда глобальным делать?

Comment: Лучше да. Хотя если таймер однократный, то можно объявить его в методе

Comment: @Alex455, а иначе как Вы его потом останавливать будете?